# Why i'm getting NaN in alert?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding two numbers, but I am getting NaN in the alert.  For example, doing 10+10 returns NaN in the alert.  What am doing wrong in this code?

```
   function calcy(){
        let a = document.getElementById('in1').Value; 
        let b = document.getElementById('in2').Value;

        let total = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        alert(total);
    }


    <div class="inputs">
          <div class="input1">
              <input type="text" id="in1">
          </div>
          <div class="input2">
              <input type="text" id="in2">
          </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: `Value` -> `value`

Comment: Side remark: if you use `type="number"`, you can use `.valueAsNumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the **.Value** to **.value;**

Try below code :

```
<script>
function calcy(){
        let a = document.getElementById('in1').value; 
        let b = document.getElementById('in2').value;

        console.log("a ="+a);
        console.log("b ="+b);
        let total = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        console.log("total ="+total);
        alert(total);
    }
</script>

    <div class="inputs">
          <div class="input1">
              <input type="text" id="in1">
          </div>
          <div class="input2">
              <input type="text" id="in2">
          </div>
          
         <button onclick="calcy()" >Click</button>
     </div>
```